# Term For IPA Phonemes With Voiced/Unvoiced Pairs

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa

Is there a term for phoneme pairs such as [p b] or [s z] which have a voiced and unvoiced variant?

**Additional Clarification**:
In an IPA table, sounds like [p] and [b] are usually paired in the same cell. Is there a term sound types (cells) that have more than one phoneme in them.

Comment: Do you mean a single word that encompasses that expresses the notion "same except for voicing"? No.

Comment: Perhaps, "voicing congeners".

Comment: Congeners are things that share a property, but differ only by a property.

Comment: @user6726. [p] and [b] are not (at least in English) the "same except for voicing". They are distinguished also by aspiration and intensity.

Comment: @user6726 - No, I know what a minimal pair is. Please see my additional clarification.

Comment: @fdb, you probably meant /p/ and /b/ are not the same except for voicing.

Comment: @Adam_G, I'm not asking if you know what a minimal pair is, I'm asking if you are looking for a phrase versus a word to describe the situation, and if the situation you are referring to is the relationship between segment pairs that are the same in terms of properties in the IPA phonetic taxonomy, except that one is voiced and the other is voiceless. That would exclude English /p, b/ since there is an aspiration difference, but "intensity" isn't an IPA classificatory category. The answer is still "No".

Comment: One could just as easily draw the table with different cell definitions, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no specific term because you do not need it. If you want to speak about [p] and [b] without distinction of voicedness, you just speak about "bilabial occlusives", which covers both the voiced and unvoiced variant. Should you really somehow need to coin an ad-hoc term, I guess "voicing pairs" would be understandable in the context.